# Handle HttpWebRequest Url size issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 (as Universal app). I'm trying to get size using this code:

```
    async public void LoadInformation(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            //var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

            if (response == null)
                return;
            string pageSource = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            string Size = CalculateBytes(response.ContentLength.ToString());

            var dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                string title = txtTitle.Text;
                txtTitle.Text = title + " | " + Size;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("LoadInformationError:\t" + ex.Message); }
    }
```

In some of URL it returns an error:

```
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

But that URL is correct and can download by Internet Explorer. Screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU51s.png

I'v used this method multiple times at the same time in multiple UserControls (each 1 UserControl load size just 1 time), do you think this is the reason?

On the debug Menu in Exceptions, I'v checked 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' for finding another issues not for this issue. Screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWInX.png

Comment: Please [do not put tags to your question's title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/247579), unless it's necessary.

Comment: Try changing the request.Method HEAD to GET and see if you get same results. i'm not sure if HEAD still has the correct contentlenght since it's not actually sending any content while GET is. at least it gives you some more pointers if that is working or not.

Comment: @Romasz OK, thanks. --           GeertvdC: I used Get method before you said and didn't catch anything (I mean ContentLength)! but by HEAD method I can gets size in some of my URL.